# Passing String Resource text/data using getExtras and Intent (Android App)

Tags: android, string, android-intent, android-resources

I don't know whether what I want is possible (I'm sure it is to the experts) but my problem is this:

I have an activity that has a listview of electronic devices, etc, which has been set up in an array list.  When I click on an item in the list, it opens another activity and displays an image using the code below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_evidence_items);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    evidenceItem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewEvidenceItem);
    evidenceInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEvidenceInfo);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        toolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("EvidenceType"));
        if (toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Main computer unit")) {
            evidenceItem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(EvidenceItemsActivity.this,
                    R.drawable.tower));
        }else if (toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Monitor")) {
            evidenceItem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(EvidenceItemsActivity.this,
                    R.drawable.monitor));
        }else if (toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Keyboard and mouse")) {
            evidenceItem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(EvidenceItemsActivity.this,
                    R.drawable.keyboardmouse));
```

The list is longer but I didn't want to bore you all.

You will see I have also set up a textview (textViewEvidenceInfo) which is where my question has arisen.  I want to know if it's possible to set up a string resource (like the below)....

```
<string name="harddisk_txt">Protect from magnetic fields.  Place in anti-static bags or in tough paper bags
or wrap in paper and place in aerated bags.</string>
```

....and put it with the bundle in order to add it to the activity, under the (drawable) image.

Could it be added to the IF statement or does it need to be separate? If indeed it is possible.

The adapter with the intent is below:

```
lvEvidence = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEvidence);

    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EvidenceTypesActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.seized_item));

    lvEvidence.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(EvidenceTypesActivity.this, EvidenceItemsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EvidenceType", lvEvidence.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    lvEvidence.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

Hope this makes sense to someone.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:

Let's say that you have the following `strig-array`

```
<string-array name="seized_item">
    <item>name1</item>
    <item>name2</item>
    <item>name3</item>
    <item>name4</item>
    <item>name5</item>
    <item>name...</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="seized_item_txt">
    <item>name1 text: Protect from magnetic fields. </item>
    <item>name2 text:</item>
    <item>name3 text:</item>
    <item>name4 text:</item>
    <item>name5 text:</item>
    <item>name... text:</item>
</string-array>
```

In your click listener put the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EvidenceTypesActivity.this, EvidenceItemsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EvidenceType", lvEvidence.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
intent.putExtra("EvidenceText", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.seized_item_txt)[i]);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your other activity:

```
evidenceItem.setImageDrawable(...)
evidenceInfo.setText(bundle.getString("EvidenceText"))
```

----last answer-----

If I got you right, you can just add another parameter to the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), evidenceActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EvidenceType", evidenceType);
intent.putExtra("text", getString(R.string.harddisk_txt));
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity:

```
toolbar.setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("EvidenceType"));
String text  = getIntent().getStringExtra("EvidenceText");
```

Or if you would like to use the Bundle object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), evidenceActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("EvidenceType", evidenceType);
b.putString("text", getString(R.string.harddisk_txt));
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the next activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("EvidenceType"));
    String text = bundle.getString("text")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I should have made it more clear that I'm using an adapter with the array which means I can't just pass the 'harddisk_txt' resource because I want it to identify a particular resource for a particular part of the array (if that makes sense?).  I'll edit my question to include the adapter code with the intent

Comment: I don't sure I understood. R.array.seized_item is a string array that represents items name, and each item has it's own description that you want to pass to the next activity when the same item gets clicked?

Comment: Yes that's right.  I have successfully passed an image to the next activity when the item gets clicked.  I'm just wanting to add some text underneath the image

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer.  I can see what you've done but I can't see how I get that new array into the textbox under the imageview )textViewEvidenceInfo).

Comment: I have tried adding what you've said.  I've also tried adding this to the IF statement: evidenceInfo.getResources().getString(R.string.harddisk_txt);  (evidenceInfo being the textbox

Comment: edited my answer, could you please check that again?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this.  The text is still not showing up.  I've tried adding a scrollView to see if the text was just off-screen but it's not.  I was just wondering, in you earlier solutions, you added the following: String text = bundle.getString("EvidenceInfo"); under the 'toolbar.setTitle' line.  Is that still needed or should it be taken out or amended?

Comment: this line `String text = bundle.getString("EvidenceInfo");` should get the right text to be displayed as well as the `evidenceInfo.setText(bundle.getString("text"))` line.
About the text not showing. In the debugger can you see that you get the right value from the bundle?

Comment: No it doesn't.  I get the following:

Comment: 01-22 21:07:41.986 1607-1626/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.android.frapp/.EvidenceItemsActivity: +1s224ms
01-22 21:07:42.008 30426-30476/com.example.android.frapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa9ed4fa0
01-22 21:07:43.869 1329-1641/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 58853100 , only wrote 58717291

Comment: where exactly this error occurred? on which line of the code?

Comment: I don't know how you'd be able to tell that.  All I know is that this is what came up when I click on an item in the EvidenceTypesActivity page

Comment: But that's just it.  It's not failing as such.  There's just no text being displayed.  And the lines of code I put above are from when I debugged

Comment: Just thought I'd let you know that for some reason, after a clean up and rebuild, I got your last suggestion to work.  So, thanks for sticking with it.  I'v marked the answer as correct

Answer (score -2):

Text=<%=item["name1"].ToString() %> not worke in butten aspx Text=<%=item["name1"].ToString() %>and that not